# Trying to load images from a local directory using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load images from a local directory using jQuery, I get this error:

```
file:///Users/[username]/Desktop/the/pics/Failed to load resource: Failed to load resource: file is directory
```

I am trying to use jquery to arrange a bunch of pictures on a page, in the same size next to each other.

I have an index file on the desktop with the image folder on the desktop as well within /the/pics directory. The index file looks as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Images</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    var dir = "the/pics/";
    var fileextension = ".jpeg";
    $.ajax({

      url: dir,
      success: function(data) {
        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function() {
          var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
          $("body").append("<div class=\"crop\" ><img src='" + dir + filename + "'></div>");
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .crop {
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .crop img {
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you read about the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). The problem is, that for security reasons, all local file accesses are strictly limited when trying to access them via javascript, _especially_ when invoked from a script residing on a local html file.

Comment: @Psi thanks, that makes sense! so do I need a web server to do this? Could I just do it using mamp?

Comment: In fact, that's the only solution I can think of. Using XAMP (including MAMP) will be the best solution, I would say.

Comment: @psi Or, if you have [node](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed you could use something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or build your own simple server [using Express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) or something else like it. I usually build a simple server into my [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) build scripts for testing.

Comment: OK, I should have made myself more clear: Using a webserver is the only group of solutions I can think of, and using XAMP is the best one among them ;-) But you're right, you can even create an own HTTP-Server to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to processing local files from javascript, there are a lot of security means that get involved here. For example, you can only read files from several folders (e.g., you won't even have access to to %WINDOWS%\Fonts in a file upload browser window at least in Firefox 55).

This gets even more restrictive when this javascript resides in a local file rather than in a website served via HTTP. This prevents attack vectors where a simple piece of HTML gets written to your disk (e.g. your cache) and then accidentally or maliciously executed.

Although it sounds counterintuitive: Scripts residing in local html files have the least privileges.

One of the reasons is the [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) which states that only those resources are trustworthy that are served from the same webserver for the same domain. (In fact, it states a little bit more, including how to whitelist resources etc.)

But fact is: Each file on the hard drive is taken as a distinct location, this includes the image files, as there are no domains where these files could belong to. And this means: No script access on local images.

All in all it is a pretty good security measure, provided that it is implemented correctly.

The only thing you can do in this case is: Make sure your script (and the html page it is located in) is served via http. If necessary, use your `hosts`-file to add local domains you need to address or set up an own dns server.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo,

The browser blocks it for security reasons [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

You can use just a simple python http server to have a static server
just run this line inside the folder you want to serve
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`